# How can i get all rows from two tables Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a problem with JOIN of two tables.

```sql
CREATE table appointment(
    idappointment serial primary key,
    idday int references days(idday),
    worktime text
    );
    create table booking(
    idbooking serial,
    idappointment int references appointment(idappointment),
    date date,
    primary key(idappointment)
);
```

appointment

| idappointment | idday | worktime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 07:00-08:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 08:00-09:00 |
| 3 | 1 | 09:00-10:00 |
| 4 | 2 | 09:00-10:00 |

booking

| idbooking | idappointment | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-08-22 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-08-2 |

And I want :

| idbooking | idappointment | date | idbooking | idappointment | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 07:00-08:00 | null | null | null |
| 2 | 1 | 08:00-09:00 | null | null | null |
| 3 | 1 | 09:00-10:00 | null | null | null |
| 4 | 2 | 09:00-10:00 | null | null | null |
| null | null | null | 1 | 1 | 2021-08-22 |
| null | null | null | 1 | 2 | 2021-08-2 |
| 1 | 1 | 07:00-08:00 | 1 | 1 | 2021-08-22 |
| 2 | 1 | 08:00-09:00 | 1 | 2 | 2021-08-2 |

How can I get it ?

[image: Tables that I want]

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: Please update the question with your query, not posting as a comment. Mark the query as code the same as you id with table definitions.

Comment: The queries posted will not return anything as they will not run. In each you are joining `b.idtermin=a.idtermin`. However the column `idtermin` does not exist in either table. Nor is there any column similar to it suggesting it is just a typo. Please correct.